# Каким образом можно ограничиться небольшим кол-вом потоков при загрузке в базу данных(Postgres)?

Tags: java, postgresql, многопоточность, spring-jdbc

Каким образом можно ограничиться небольшим кол-вом потоков при загрузке циклом данных в базу данных(Postgres)?
Имею больше >30000 значений для внедрения, из них загружает 196 и бросает

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: sorry, too many clients
> already

Через конфиг увеличивать кол-во потоков и буфер не кажется разумным в этой ситуации.
Только недавно начал изучать Spring, примерно понимаю, что нужно каким-то образом делать это с минимальным кол-вом потоков и ожиданием, но не совсем понимаю, как это реализовать.
Открываю соединение  через JdbcTemplate

Код выглядит следующим образом:

```
@Autowired
    public void loadIntoDb() throws Throwable {

    for (int i = 0; i <= Parser.lenght; i++)

        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO db VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", someObject.getList().get(i).getString(), createStringSqlArray(someObject.getList().get(i).getAnotherList()), someObject.getList().get(i).getString(), someObject.getList().get(i).getInt(), createStringSqlArray(someObject.getList().get(i).getAnotherList()));
}

private java.sql.Array createStringSqlArray(List<String> list) {
    java.sql.Array strArray = null;
    try {
        strArray = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection().createArrayOf("text", list.toArray());
    } catch (SQLException ignore) {
    }
    return strArray;

}
```

Comment: переопределил finalize, кол-во данных, добавленных в таблицу, увеличилось почти в два раза(350), но это все еще не то

Comment: Вероятно, ты исчерпал не количество потоков, а количество подключений к базе данных. Если создавать подключение в цикле, то такая ошибка быстро появится. Попробуй воспользоваться пулом соединений. Например hikariCP или пул от компании "одноклассники"

Comment: @AnsarOzden
При использовании HikariCP ловлю
_java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-4 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms_

  c   `hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(120000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Особого смысла запускать большое количество потоков - нет. Увеличение количества потоков имеет смысл до определенного предела, а дальше ресурсы сервера БД или ресурсы компьютера, где вы запускаете свое приложение, или пропускная способность сети станут узким горлышком и потоки все равно будут ждать конкурируя за ресурсы (или вообще их все исчерпают, как в вашем случае). Обычно речь идет максимум о десятке (а чаще еще меньше) потоков, и точно не о сотне.

Гораздо лучше со всех точек зрения загружать данные из небольшого количества потоков, используя одно и то же соединение к БД в каждом потоке. Это можно делать или с помощью connection pool типа HikariCP, если существующая структура вашего приложения подразумевает/требует открытия новых соединений, или просто повторно используя тот же объект javax.sql.Connection (хотя если вы используете jdbcTeamplate, то прямое использование `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource()` выглядит подозрительным - это неканоническое использование `jdbcTemplate`) для выполнения запросов.

Далее, имеет смысл рассмотреть использовать batch вставку используя `batchUpdate` из `jdbcTemplate` (что под капотом будет использовать PreparedStatement). Это обычно не требует больших переделок программы.

Еще лучше для вставки данных использовать операцию [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-copy.html) с помощью [CopyManager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html). Это самый лучший по производительности способ, но требует определенных изменений в программе.

После того как добавили код видно, что как минимум одна большая проблема с тем что создается новое соединение `jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()`несколько раз на одной итерации цикла и никогда не закрывается. Каждой итерации создается 2 новых соединения, так что на сервере очень быстро достигается лимит. Делайте как-то так (это ручное повторное использование соединения, как я предлагал выше):

```
@Autowired
    public void loadIntoDb() throws Throwable {

    try (Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= Parser.lenght; i++)

        jdbcTemplate.update(
            "INSERT INTO db VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", 
            someObject.getList().get(i).getString(), 
            createStringSqlArray(
              connection,
              someObject.getList().get(i).getAnotherList()), 
            someObject.getList().get(i).getString(), 
            someObject.getList().get(i).getInt(), 
            createStringSqlArray(
              connection,
              someObject.getList().get(i).getAnotherList()));
}

private java.sql.Array createStringSqlArray(Connection connection, List<String> list) {
    java.sql.Array strArray = null;
    try {
        strArray = connection.createArrayOf("text", list.toArray());
    } catch (SQLException ignore) {
    }
    return strArray;

}
```

Ну или если есть сконфигурирован connection pool, то можно оставить создание соединения в методе `createStringSqlArray`, но добавить закрытие (это повторное использование соединения с помощью пула):

```
    try (Connection connection = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection()) {
        strArray = connection.createArrayOf("text", list.toArray());
    } catch (SQLException ignore) {
    }
```

А еще лучше не открывать соединение для создания sql array вовсе, а использовать готовое с помощью org.springframework.jdbc.support.SqlValue, как описано [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55398179/2231972)

Comment: `getDataSource()` использовал исключительно чтобы посмотреть, изменится ли что-либо, в коде его не использую.
При использовании HikariCP ловлю
_java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-4 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms_

  c    `hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(30);
        hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(120000);`
 Почему-то потоки настойчиво не хотят освобождаться

Comment: @BobRob Сколько одновременно открытых соединений вы создаете? Сколько потоков запускаете?

Comment: я кажись понял. У меня добавление в дб идет в таком порядке - берется объект - у него извлекается массив, в котором лежат объекты с еще одним массивом. И вот я пытаюсь последний массив ложить в дб. Каким образом можно обойти дедлок базы в таких случаях? Отдельным тред-пулом?

Comment: Так мы не продвинемся. Нужно ответить на вопросы что я задал в предыдущем комментарии. Не понимая в чем причина проблемы, ее не решить. А я не понимаю, в частности, сколько вы создаете соединений и сколько потоков. Не важно сколько вы объектов вставляете в БД, важно как вы это делаете. Можно вставить и миллион объектов без проблем. А код вы не показали и на уточняющие вопросы не отвечаете, так что я не знаю, что именно вы делаете не так.

Comment: добавил класс с кодом, по поводу потоков - запускаются 30 и не закрываются. Могу предоставить любую часть кода, просто с этим впервые для себя разбираюсь и не все понимаю